# Apache web server and Tomcat in Windows

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, grails

I need to run the web server as some folks use PHP and some use Groovy and Grails that runs on Tomcat. My company only allows port 80 to pass through.

Can I get a detailed instructions on how to support both in this case?

Answer (score 1):

use nginx as a proxy server which listen on 80 port.
define different upstream for php and tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Proxy your Grails application through a dedicated web server like Apache, Nginx, or Lighttp.

For Apache, enable mod_proxy and have it listen on port 80.  Run your Grails application in Tomcat listening on another port, such as 8080.  Then configure Apache to proxy to your Grails app:

```
# ensure these modules get loaded
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /mygrailsapp http://localhost:8080/mygrailsapp
ProxyPassReverse /mygrailsapp http://localhost:8080/mygrailsapp
```

You can then configure Apache to serve up PHP directly or proxy to another server.

Answer (score 0):

Install and configure **mod_jk** module so that Apache would forward requests to Tomcat for a particuliar path while listening on port 80.

See the documentation of  [mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/mod_jk-howto.html).

Apache config:

```
# send all requests to "/grails" to Tomcat    
JkMount /grails/* worker
```

Tomcat server.xml (uncomment the AJP connector)

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3" />
```

Answer (score -2):

You can configure Apache server to listen to a particular port... edit the http.conf file... add:
 `Listen 8080`
That should do it, if you need to add the server's IP address: 
`172.x.x.x:80`